# How can I toggle the images for this expand/collapse button using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to be able to expand/collapse a menu, I can do that, but by clicking the button, and the button image should change based on the state of the collapsed menu.

Here's the code I was trying, but I can't seem to get it to work like I wanted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle1').click(function() {
        $('#collapse1').slideToggle(400);   
        if (visible) {
            $('#toggle2').attr('src', 'media/collapse.png');
        }
        else {
            $('#toggle2').attr('src', 'media/expand.png');
        }
    });
    $('#toggle2').click(function() {
        $('#collapse2').slideToggle(400);
        if (visible) {
            $('#toggle2').attr('src', 'media/collapse.png');
        }
        else {
            $('#toggle2').attr('src', 'media/expand.png');
        }       
    });
});
```

Could anyone offer some advice?

Comment: Where does the `visible` variable come from?

Comment: can you provide your html code related to this part also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example I created for another question similar to this in here. check that:
http://jsfiddle.net/wFQ7U/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the `visible` variable is true or not, just check if image src is `'media/expand.png'`.